# Positioning pictures in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Below code count pictures that are pasted (by other macro) as msorectangle shape in excel worksheet and position them in 1 row in specific distance beetween each of them. I need to add another restrctions to positioning and im struggling with coding it. Question is how to upgrade this code if:

1. If number of pictures is <=6 than 1 row of pictures and set size to h:7,25cm w:4,7cm
2. If number of pictures is >6 and <=11 then 1 row of pictures with size h:5,9cm w:3,8cm
3. If number of pictures is =12 than 2 rows with size from 1 point h:7,25cm w:4,7cm.
4. If number of pictures is >12 than every (7, 13, 19, 25 etc. pic) is starting from next row with size from point nr 2 h:5,9cm w:3,8cm

### The list of pictures is dynamic.

```
Sub Sample2()
Dim shp As Shape, shp2 As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lstShp As Integer
Dim shpLft As Double, shpTop As Double, shpWidth As Double, shpHeight As Double
Dim inBetweenMargin As Double
Dim i As Long

    '~~> In betwen margin
    inBetweenMargin = 8 


    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("wk")

    With ws
        '~~> Get the max shape number(name)
        For Each shp In .Shapes
            If shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then
                If Val(shp.Name) > 1 And Val(shp.Name) > lstShp Then _
                lstShp = Val(shp.Name)
            End If
        Next

        '~~> Loop through the shapes
        For i = 1 To lstShp
            '~~> This is required in case you delete shape 3
            '~~> and have only shapes 1,2,4,5 etc...
            On Error Resume Next
            Set shp = .Shapes(CStr(i))
            'shp2 = first photo
            Set shp2 = ws.Shapes("1")
            On Error GoTo 0

            '~~> position them
            If Not shp Is Nothing And shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then
                If shpLft = 0 And shpTop = 0 And shpWidth = 0 Then
                    shpLft = shp.Left
                    shpTop = shp.Top
                    shpWidth = shp.Width
                Else

                    shp.Top = shpTop
                    shp.Left = shpLft + shpWidth + inBetweenMargin

                    shpLft = shp.Left
                    shpWidth = shp.Width
                End If
            End If

         'position picture nr 7 and above in second row
        If Val(shp.Name) = 7 Then
            shp.Top = shp2.Top + shp2.Height + inBetweenMargin
            shp.Left = shp2.Left

            shpLft = shp.Left
            shpWidth = shp.Width
        End If

        If Val(shp.Name) >= 8 Then
            shp.Top = shp2.Top + shp2.Height + inBetweenMargin
        End If

        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout maybe you can still help me with your code to solve these 4 restrictions? I managed to do second row but other stuff is too overhelming for me as for now.

Comment: Your statement: `If Val(shp.Name) = 7 Then` doesn't do what your comment suggests. If you want it to do for all shapes with number 7 or above, than change it to: `If Val(shp.Name) >= 7 Then`. As far as your conditions/requirements are concerned, can you not just use a `Select` statement instead of `If Val(shp.Name) = 7 Then` and set your conditions there? or have I misunderstood your requirements?

Comment: One moment.. Looking at it

Comment: @Zac i had to do Val(shp.Name) = 7 and go to Val(shp.Name) >= 8 because i had all pictures above 7 in same place. With that code i place pic 7 below pic 1 and pictures above 7 are placed right to 7 than 8 and so on.

Comment: I had posted an answer but had to delete it as I misunderstood what you wanted.. I thought you wanted a minimum of 7 images per row...

Comment: What happens when the number of shapes is less than `6`? or when the number of shapes is exactly `7`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout i edited the restrictions a bit. When less than 6 than one row of pictures starting from pic 1 to 6 (with bigger size). If i have 7 than have to resize it to (smaller size) to fit one row.

Comment: For the last 2 conditions can you specify the size in cms? since we are dealing in cms?

Comment: Also i think you are still not sure of your conditions? What would haeppen if there are 6 shapes? you have covered<6 and >6... but not =6

Comment: @SiddharthRout sorry, doing my best to describe what i want to achive. If 6 shapes than your first code is ok (just 6 pictures in 1 row with size h:7,25cm w:4,7cm)

Comment: @SiddharthRout added cms in last 2 conditions, hope its that what you ask for. Sorry for messing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 2nd last condition, if the total picture count is 12 then I am safely assuming that you need 6 per line. And for the last condition you want 7 per line. For these two we will use a `Counter` and then we will do either `Counter Mod 6` or `Counter Mod 7` for that purpose. You can read about [Mod operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mod-operator) in MS KB.

The logic is to reset the `.Top` and `.Left` in the next line for the last 2 conditions.We will use a boolean variable for that.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As Shape, shp2 As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lstShp As Integer
    Dim shpLft As Single, shpTop As Single, shpWidth As Single, shpHeight As Single
    Dim oldLeft As Single, oldTop As Single
    Dim inBetweenMargin As Single
    Dim i As Long, counter As Long, picCount As Long
    Dim nextLine As Boolean, MultipleRows As Boolean
    Dim ModByNumber As Long

    '~~> In betwen margin
    inBetweenMargin = 8

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Get the max shape number(name)
        For Each shp In .Shapes
            If shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then
                If Val(shp.Name) > 1 And Val(shp.Name) > lstShp Then _
                lstShp = Val(shp.Name)
                picCount = picCount + 1
            End If
        Next

        Select Case picCount
            Case 1 To 6
                '~~> Set your default height and Width
                shpHeight = 7.25 * 28.34646 '<~~ Cm to Points
                shpWidth = 4.7 * 28.34646 '<~~ Cm to Points
            Case 7 To 11
                '~~> Set your default height and Width
                shpHeight = 5.9 * 28.34646 '<~~ Cm to Points
                shpWidth = 3.8 * 28.34646 '<~~ Cm to Points
            Case 12
                '~~> Set your default height and Width
                shpHeight = 7.25 * 28.34646 '<~~ Cm to Points
                shpWidth = 4.7 * 28.34646 '<~~ Cm to Points
                MultipleRows = True
                ModByNumber = 6
            Case Is > 12
                '~~> Set your default height and Width
                shpHeight = 5.9 * 28.34646 '<~~ Cm to Points
                shpWidth = 3.8 * 28.34646 '<~~ Cm to Points
                MultipleRows = True
                ModByNumber = 7
        End Select

        nextLine = False

        '~~> Loop through the shapes
        For i = 1 To lstShp
            '~~> This is required in case you delete shape 3
            '~~> and have only shapes 1,2,4,5 etc...
            On Error Resume Next
            Set shp = .Shapes(CStr(i))
            On Error GoTo 0

            '~~> position them
            If Not shp Is Nothing Then
                If shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then
                    If shpLft = 0 And shpTop = 0 Then
                        shpLft = shp.Left
                        shpTop = shp.Top
                        shp.Height = shpHeight
                        shp.Width = shpWidth

                        '~~> Storing the top and left for resetting
                        '~~> when moving to next line
                        oldTop = shp.Top
                        oldLeft = shp.Left

                        counter = counter + 1
                    Else
                        shp.Top = shpTop
                        oldTop = shpTop

                        If nextLine = True Then
                            shp.Left = shpLft
                            nextLine = False
                            counter = 1
                        Else
                            shp.Left = shpLft + shpWidth + inBetweenMargin
                            counter = counter + 1
                        End If

                        shp.Height = shpHeight
                        shp.Width = shpWidth

                        shpLft = shp.Left

                        If MultipleRows = True Then
                            If counter Mod ModByNumber = 0 Then
                                shpLft = oldLeft
                                shpTop = oldTop + shpHeight + inBetweenMargin
                                nextLine = True
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            '~~> This is required if there is no shape between 4 and 6.
            '~~> 5 gets deleted? Also the reason why we are not using "i Mod 7"
            '~~> and using "counter Mod 7"
            Set shp = Nothing
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshots**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont think he wants 7 pics per row. Every 7th picture on a new row == 6 per row.

Comment: @Luuklag yeah i wanted every 7th picture in new row as you say.

Comment: @SiddharthRout wow, this works like a charm i just edited modbynumber in last case to 6. This is some next level of vba for me, hope i will get it some day. Need to read about this case thing because its useful. Thank you all!

Comment: @Tomz: yes if it is 6 pic per row then `ModByNumber = 7` will become `ModByNumber = 6` :)

Answer (score 1):

> - If number of pictures is 6 than 1 row and set size to h:7,25cm    w:4,7cm
> - If number of pictures is >7 and <=10 then 1 row of pictures with size h:5,9cm w:3,8cm
> - If number of pictures is <12 than 2 rows with size from 1 point.
> - If number of pictures is >12 than every 7 pic is starting from next row with size from point nr 2

So if we take `i` as the amount of pictures:

We can do some simple calculations to check which condition is met and use `Select Case` 
to identify and assign each of your 4 cases like so:

```
Select Case i
    Case IS >= 12
        numberofrows = i \ 7 '(this only gives whole numbers)
        Formatting = 2
    Case IS > 10
        numberofrows = 2
        Formatting = 1
    Case IS >= 7
        numberofrows = 1
        Formatting = 2
    Case ELSE
        numberofrows = 1
        Formatting = 1
End Select
```